# TaskScheduler.Current and TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() difference?

Tags: c#, task, scheduler

I have a task to get products from database, and the `ContinueWith` action that operate some UI modification, therefore I had a problem because the Task create a new thread, and the UI modification was executed not in the UI Thread.

I tried to use this fix :

```
var currentScheduler = TaskScheduler.Current;

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{    
    // get products   
}).ContinueWith((x) => handleProductsArrived(x.Result, x.Exception), currentScheduler);
```

but it didn't work at all. I check and the `ContinueWith` was not executed in the thread from currentScheduler but in an another.

I discovered this method :

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // get products
}).ContinueWith((x) => handleProductsArrived(x.Result, x.Exception), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

and it works. So what's the differences? Why didn't my first code work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the documentation for `TaskScheduler.Current`:

> When not called from within a task, Current will return the Default scheduler.

Then from the [Task Schedulers documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402.aspx):

> The default scheduler for Task Parallel Library and PLINQ uses the .NET Framework ThreadPool to queue and execute work.

So if you use `TaskScheduler.Current` when you're not in a task, you'll get a scheduler which uses the thread pool.

If you call `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`, you'll get one for the current [synchronization context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) - which in Windows Forms or WPF (when called from a UI thread) is a context which schedules work on the relevant UI thread.

So that's why the first code didn't work: it executed your continuation on a thread pool thread. Your second code executed the continuation on the UI thread.

Note that if you can use C# 5 and async/await, all of this is handled *much* more simply.

Comment: This is useful when you can't use async/await like in a constructor of a UI component, right?

Comment: @Chin: I wouldn't particularly use it for that - I'd generally have a static async method which does the work and then calls a quick constructor.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on that? Particularly I have another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886276/handle-exception-when-using-task-run-in-ui-constructor that is kinda related to that

Comment: @Chin
Constructor(){
DoHeavyWorkAndUpdate();
}

private async void DoHeavyWorkAndUpdate(){
await Task.Run(()=>{... /*compute here, runs on background thread*/ });
/*this runs on the main thread*/
UpdateUI();
}

Comment: @JonSkeet What would be the "_much_ more simple" solution? I would really like to use that. My problem: I have a base class, that will be used heavily by other classes. I would like to initialize some properties only after every inherited class constructor was executed. So creating a task on the current synccontext is what I came up. I feel like async await should be able to solve this, but I couldn't figure out.

Comment: @Kobor42: Please ask with details on a new question, rather than in comments on a question which is 10 years old, and which sounds like it isn't really the same as the original question.