# Handle exception when using Task.Run() in UI constructor

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a constructor that call `Task.Run()` like this:

```
public MyPage() {
    Task.Run(() => {
        MyHeavyCpuMethod();
    });
}
```

Here, `MyPage()` is the constructor of a UI component, and I don't want `MyHeavyCpuMethod()` to run on my UI thread, so I offload it with `Task.Run()` in a fire-and-forget fashion since I don't really care when `MyHeavyCpuMethod()` finishes.

However, this way if `MyHeavyCpuMethod()` throws, I can't handle the exception that is in the returned Task.

How can I do error handling in this case?

Comment: I think you want to break some design rules thus faces problems. The constructors intended to be used to ensure invariant of object.

Comment: How would I do it the correct way then?

Comment: It depends what is your intention when you fire and forget the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use async/await... which doesn't work with a constructor, but which *can* work in a static method:

```
public static async Task<MyPage> CreateInstance()
{
    await Task.Run(...);
    // Anything else asynchronous you want to use
    return new MyPage();
}
```

And then assuming you're *using* this from an async method, you can just use:

```
MyPage page = await MyPage.CreateInstance();
```

That way, if the CPU-bound task fails, you won't even get to the constructor call. The constructor call itself is expected to be fast here, as that *will* be on the UI thread (as you want it to be).

An alternative to this, you could potentially store the task returned by `Task.Run` as a field in the page, and then await that post-construction... using the normal async exception handling approaches.

Comment: But how do you handle the case where you don't have any control on how and when the constructor is called? For example, in a Windows Store app, we would have a `Page` that will be constructed automatically on app launch. If I want to do some heavy updates on the page every time the page is created, but I have (no ?) control of when and how the page is created, what would I do?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `ContinueWith` that only fires when the `Task` doesn't run to completion (throws an exception):

```
Task.Run(() => MyHeavyCpuMethod())
    .ContinueWith(task => { /* some action */  }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Your second task will not be run on the UI thread either, per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Creates a continuation that executes asynchronously when the target Task completes.

You can play with a dummy method to try it out:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
      throw new Exception();
}).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => MessageBox.Show("ERROR")));
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Comment: Yes, anything inside ContinueWith will be executed on UI thread once the control comes back from MyHeavyCpuMethod.

Comment: Then how can I propagate the exception back to the main UI thread? What would happen if I rethrow it inside the ContinueWith()? Say, if I just want to make the app crash, what do I have to do?

Comment: invoke the method in your ContinueWith: `Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => MessageBox.Show("ERROR")));`

Comment: @AliBaig It is not true unless you pass `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`  to `ContinueWith`

Comment: Oh yes! That parameter is skipped unintentionally :)